# Efficiently insert or replace multiple elements in the middle or at the beginning of a Vec?

Tags: rust

Is there any straightforward way to insert or replace multiple elements from `&[T]` and/or `Vec<T>` in the middle or at the beginning of a `Vec` in linear time?

I could only find [`std::vec::Vec::insert`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.insert), but that's only for inserting a single element in `O(n)` time, so I obviously cannot call that in a loop.

I *could* do a `split_off` at that index, `extend` the new elements into the left half of the split, and then `extend` the second half into the first, but is there a better way?

Comment: `split_off` is O(n) however, just like `insert`. AFAIK, with Vec, all methods of adding elements at a random position are O(n). A more efficient solution to the “set index i to this item and j+1 to items at j ≥ i” relies on BTreeMap, in O(log n).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As of Rust 1.21.0, [`Vec::splice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice) is available and allows inserting at any point, including fully prepending:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 5];
let slice = &[2, 3, 4];

vec.splice(1..1, slice.iter().cloned());

println!("{:?}", vec); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The docs state:

> Note 4: This is optimal if:
>
> - The tail (elements in the vector after range) is empty
> - or `replace_with` yields fewer elements than range’s length
> - or the lower bound of its `size_hint()` is exact.

In this case, the lower bound of the slice's iterator should be exact, so it should perform one memory move.

---

`splice` is a bit more powerful in that it allows you to remove a range of  values (the first argument), insert new values (the second argument), and optionally get the old values (the result of the call).

**Replacing a set of items**

```
let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 5];
let slice = &[2, 3, 4];

vec.splice(..2, slice.iter().cloned());

println!("{:?}", vec); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Getting the previous values**

```
let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
let slice = &[9, 8, 7];

let old: Vec<_> = vec.splice(3.., slice.iter().cloned()).collect();

println!("{:?}", vec); // [0, 1, 2, 9, 8, 7]
println!("{:?}", old); // [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 10):

Okay, there is no appropriate method in *Vec* interface (as I can see). But we can always implement the same thing ourselves.

#### memmove

When **T** is **Copy**, probably the most obvious way is to move the memory, like this:

```
fn push_all_at<T>(v: &mut Vec<T>, offset: usize, s: &[T]) where T: Copy {
    match (v.len(), s.len()) {
        (_, 0) => (),
        (current_len, _) => {
            v.reserve_exact(s.len());
            unsafe {
                v.set_len(current_len + s.len());
                let to_move = current_len - offset;
                let src = v.as_mut_ptr().offset(offset as isize);
                if to_move > 0 {
                    let dst = src.offset(s.len() as isize);
                    std::ptr::copy_memory(dst, src, to_move);
                }
                std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping_memory(src, s.as_ptr(), s.len());
            }
        },
    }
}
```

#### shuffle

If **T** is not copy, but it implements **Clone**, we can append given slice to the end of the *Vec*, and move it to the required position using *swap*s in linear time:

```
fn push_all_at<T>(v: &mut Vec<T>, mut offset: usize, s: &[T]) where T: Clone + Default {
    match (v.len(), s.len()) {
        (_, 0) => (),
        (0, _) => { v.push_all(s); },
        (_, _) => {
            assert!(offset <= v.len());
            let pad = s.len() - ((v.len() - offset) % s.len());
            v.extend(repeat(Default::default()).take(pad));
            v.push_all(s);
            let total = v.len();
            while total - offset >= s.len() {
                for i in 0 .. s.len() { v.swap(offset + i, total - s.len() + i); }
                offset += s.len();
            }
            v.truncate(total - pad);
        },
    }
}
```

#### iterators concat

Maybe the best choice will be to not modify *Vec* at all. For example, if you are going to access the result via iterator, we can just build iterators chain from our chunks:

```
let v: &[usize] = &[0, 1, 2];
let s: &[usize] = &[3, 4, 5, 6];
let offset = 2;
let chain = v.iter().take(offset).chain(s.iter()).chain(v.iter().skip(offset));

let result: Vec<_> = chain.collect();
println!("Result: {:?}", result);
```

Comment: For the 3rd solution, instead of using `skip`, you could use `split_at`.

Comment: yes, but it will require an extra "offset < len()" check in order to prevent runtime panic.

Answer (score -3):

I was trying to prepend to a vector in rust and found [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037573/how-to-prepend-a-slice-to-a-vec) that was linked here, (despite this question being **both** prepend and insert AND efficiency. I think my answer would be better as an answer for that other, more precises question because I can't attest to the efficiency), but the following code helped me prepend, (and the opposite.) [I'm sure that the other two answers are more efficient, but the way that I learn, I like having answers that can be cut-n-pasted with examples that demonstrate an application of the answer.]

```rust
pub trait Unshift<T> { fn unshift(&mut self, s: &[T]) -> (); }
pub trait UnshiftVec<T> { fn unshift_vec(&mut self, s: Vec<T>) -> (); }
pub trait UnshiftMemoryHog<T> { fn unshift_memory_hog(&mut self, s: Vec<T>) -> (); }
pub trait Shift<T> { fn shift(&mut self) -> (); }
pub trait ShiftN<T> { fn shift_n(&mut self, s: usize) -> (); }

impl<T: std::clone::Clone> ShiftN<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn shift_n(&mut self, s: usize) -> ()
    // where
    //    T: std::clone::Clone,
    {   
        self.drain(0..s);
    }
}

impl<T: std::clone::Clone> Shift<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn shift(&mut self) -> ()
    // where
    //    T: std::clone::Clone,
    {   
        self.drain(0..1);
    }
}

impl<T: std::clone::Clone> Unshift<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn unshift(&mut self, s: &[T]) -> ()
    // where
    //    T: std::clone::Clone,
    {   
        self.splice(0..0, s.to_vec());
    }
}
impl<T: std::clone::Clone> UnshiftVec<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn unshift_vec(&mut self, s: Vec<T>) -> ()
    where
        T: std::clone::Clone,
    {   
        self.splice(0..0, s);
    }
}

impl<T: std::clone::Clone> UnshiftMemoryHog<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn unshift_memory_hog(&mut self, s: Vec<T>) -> ()
    where
        T: std::clone::Clone,
    {
        let mut tmp: Vec<_> = s.to_owned();
        //let mut tmp: Vec<_> = s.clone(); // this also works for some data types
        /*
        let local_s: Vec<_> = self.clone(); // explicit clone()
        tmp.extend(local_s);                // to vec is possible
        */
        tmp.extend(self.clone());
        *self = tmp;
        //*self = (*tmp).to_vec(); // Just because it compiles, doesn't make it right.
    }
}

// this works for: v = unshift(v, &vec![8]);
// (If you don't want to impl Unshift for Vec<T>)

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn unshift_fn<T>(v: Vec<T>, s: &[T]) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    // create a mutable vec and fill it
    // with a clone of the array that we want
    // at the start of the vec.
    let mut tmp: Vec<_> = s.to_owned();
    // then we add the existing vector to the end
    // of the temporary vector.
    tmp.extend(v);
    // return the tmp vec that is identitcal
    // to unshift-ing the original vec.
    tmp
}

/*
    N.B. It is sometimes (often?) more memory efficient to reverse
    the vector and use push/pop, rather than splice/drain;
    Especially if you create your vectors in "stack order" to begin with.
*/

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("Before push:\t {:?}", v);
    v.push(0);
    println!("After push:\t {:?}", v);
    v.pop();
    println!("popped:\t\t {:?}", v);
    v.drain(0..1);
    println!("drain(0..1)\t {:?}", v);
    /*
        // We could use a function
    let c = v.clone();
    v = unshift_fn(c, &vec![0]);
    */
    v.splice(0..0, vec![0]);
    println!("splice(0..0, vec![0]) {:?}", v);
    v.shift_n(1);
    println!("shift\t\t {:?}", v);
    v.unshift_memory_hog(vec![8, 16, 31, 1]);
    println!("MEMORY guzzler unshift {:?}", v);
    //v.drain(0..3);
    v.drain(0..=2);
    println!("back to the start: {:?}", v);
    v.unshift_vec(vec![0]);
    println!("zerothed with unshift: {:?}", v);

    let mut w = vec![4, 5, 6];
    /*
    let prepend_this = &[1, 2, 3];
    w.unshift_vec(prepend_this.to_vec());
    */
    w.unshift(&[1, 2, 3]);

    assert_eq!(&w, &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
    println!("{:?} == {:?}", &w, &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Comment: In your `unshift`, I think you'll do better with `s.iter().cloned()`, as that avoids allocating the intermediate vector.

Comment: Most of these seem like unnecessarily renamed versions of `splice`, which is already mentioned in the accepted answer, so what's the point of this answer? Do you really need to write `.unshift_vec(v)` when you can already write `.splice(..0, v)`?

Comment: I had a bunch more thoughts on this code so I compiled them into a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=291245c605b56275d8e9aa335ed358f0).

Comment: As someone with decades of habituation to push/pop being mirrored by unshift/shift, this is how I learnt the idiomatic Rust way. Maybe it will help someone else that is always open to learning.

Comment: @trentcl I found your playground very helpful. Thank you.