# Is Vec::splice() efficient when the length doesn't change?

Tags: rust, vector

When you use [`Vec::splice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice) to replace part of a `Vec`, is it smart enough to specially handle the case where the replacement is the same length as the chunk it is replacing, or should I handle that myself?

Is there any point doing this, or is `array.splice()` smart enough to do that anyway?

```
fn example(array: Vec<u64>, replacement: Vec<u64>, range: std::ops::Range<usize>) {
    if (replacement.len() == range.len()) {
        for i in range {
            array[i] = replacement[i];
        }
    } else {
        array.splice(range, replacement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which "efficient" and "smart enough" do you mean, specifically? Do you care about memory allocation, or using SIMD extensions to copy data, or moving memory more than once, or....

Comment: You can try taking a look at the source code: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2240-2248, https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2842-2956, and https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2920-2956

Comment: Was trying to avoid that since it is quite complicated, but I have no and the answer is that it is smart enough. I'll write a full answer.

Answer (score 5):

I gave in and read the code. It *is* smart enough to handle that case. Here's how the code works:

1. You call `.splice()`, it creates a `Splice` object which includes a `Drain` iterator for the replacement range:

   ```
   pub fn splice<R, I>(&mut self, range: R, replace_with: I) -> Splice<'_, I::IntoIter>
   where
       R: RangeBounds<usize>,
       I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
   {
       Splice { drain: self.drain(range), replace_with: replace_with.into_iter() }
   }
   ```
2. The `Splice` is dropped, which calls its `drop()` implementation.

   ```
   impl<I: Iterator> Drop for Splice<'_, I> {
       fn drop(&mut self) {
   ```

   The first thing it does is drop all of the elements that are being replaced.

   ```
           self.drain.by_ref().for_each(drop);
   ```

   Then it checks if the replacement is at the end of the `Vec`, if so just extend it and return.

   ```
           unsafe {
               if self.drain.tail_len == 0 {
                   self.drain.vec.as_mut().extend(self.replace_with.by_ref());
                   return;
               }
   ```

   Next it calls a helper `fill()` function, to replace the removed elements with as many as it can from the replacement iterator (`replace_with`). `fill()` returns `false` if it didn't fill the whole of the replacement range, in which case it returns (I'm not sure where the tail is moved in this case though?)

   ```
               // First fill the range left by drain().
               if !self.drain.fill(&mut self.replace_with) {
                   return;
               }
   ```

   Now `replace_with` may have 0 elements left (in which case we are done), or it may have more elements (in which case the tail needs to be moved back by that amount). This is what happens next.

   ```
               // There may be more elements. Use the lower bound as an estimate.
               // FIXME: Is the upper bound a better guess? Or something else?
               let (lower_bound, _upper_bound) = self.replace_with.size_hint();
               if lower_bound > 0 {
                   self.drain.move_tail(lower_bound);
                   if !self.drain.fill(&mut self.replace_with) {
                       return;
                   }
               }
   ```

   You might expect `if lower_bound == 0 { return; }`, but `lower_bound` is only an estimate so it tries with that first and if that fails it copies the replacement into a temporary vector, so it can know the full length.

   ```
               // Collect any remaining elements.
               // This is a zero-length vector which does not allocate if `lower_bound` was exact.
               let mut collected = self.replace_with.by_ref().collect::<Vec<I::Item>>().into_iter();
               // Now we have an exact count.
               if collected.len() > 0 {
                   self.drain.move_tail(collected.len());
                   let filled = self.drain.fill(&mut collected);
                   debug_assert!(filled);
                   debug_assert_eq!(collected.len(), 0);
               }
   ```

   The point is that if `replace_with` *is* empty, because the replacement size was the same as the range, then all of those operations are fairly simple nop-ish things.

   The final bit drops the `Drain` iterator itself, which will move the tail.. possibly again? I don't know I kind of lost track here. Anyway if the length is the same it definitely won't move it.

   ```
           }
           // Let `Drain::drop` move the tail back if necessary and restore `vec.len`.
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.splice) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47039490/3551604), `splice` is "smart" (optimal) in a few cases, including the case where "the lower bound of [`replace_with`]'s `size_hint()` is exact."

In your example function, the lower bound of `size_hint()` on `replacement.iter()` is exact, so one memory move should be performed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, [`Splice::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2879-2918) is what does most of the work, and that calls `fill`, which, in the case of matching lengths, will iterate through `replace_with`, and return `true` but leave `replace_with` empty, so `lower_bound` is 0 and `collected.len()` is 0.

[`Drain::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#2787-2827) then runs. The loop should do nothing, since `Splice::drop` already iterated over it, and then `DropGuard::drop`, which might need to shift elements over, shouldn't need to move/copy elements, since as a result of the lengths matching, `tail` should equal `start`.